# jQuery Ajax Cross-site scripting

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I know this question has been asked (many times) before but I still can't seem to get it right.

I want to perform an AJAX request in jQuery and get "arbitrary" contents - e.g. it may be html, text, json, img

When I perform something like the following I get the infamous 
**No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://mydomain.com' is therefore not allowed access.**

```
$.ajax({
            url: "http://www.pureexample.com/jquery/cross-domain-ajax.html",
            // dataType: "jsonp",
            crossDomain: true,   
            success: function (data) {
                        console.log('success');
                         console.log(data);

           },
            error: function(request, status, error) {
                    console.log('Error on request. ' + request.responseText);
                    alert('Error on request. ' + request.responseText);
                }
        });
```

*I* am not serving the data, so I cannot do anything on the server-side to allow cross domain request.  I believe specifying **JSONP** (commented out) assumes that JSON is being returned? With or without it, it does not work.

So, bottom line - is there a "simple" way to to a cross-domain request so that I may get the result and insert into a tag (e.g. html into a DIV)

Any help, or further explanation is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.
Rob

Comment: If no JSONP response is explicitly provided by the remote server, then the _only_ thing you can do is proxy those requests via your own server, so that the SOP doesn’t apply.

Answer (score 3):

I had this very problem a while ago, when using an external webservice to retrieve Brazilian's zip code data (address and such).
**And** I used the very same method you did.

There are a few points that need to be stressed out:

1) Ajax does not allow security protocol differences. That means that, if your page is secured behind a secure protocol (HTTPS), your browser will **not** allow an external server to return through an unsecured one (HTTP). (I found this late in my development, and the result was to use .NET's webrequest )

2) Setting datatype to "JSONP" doesn't *transform* a response to JSON. It *allows* it to be received as such.

3) JSONP is the *only* datatype acceptd for cross-domain requests. The error message you described is probably due to this reason.

So, to summarize:

When talking about cross-domain requests with ajax,"Arbitrary" contents are restricted to JSON(P). AND the data received MUST be JSON.

Also, until jQuery 1.5, if the response is not correctly typed as JSON, *no errors are raised* .

I wish I had known these issues before I started my development... Uploading a component to production servers unbeknownst of the fact that requesting data stored within HTTP from SSL-Layered servers is quite an embarassment. ... (Though still quite predictable, actually)

For more info : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Important note: the response to a JSONP request is not JSON.  Rather, it is a function invocation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Ajax-cross-origin a jQuery plugin.

This plugin let you use jQuery.ajax() cross domain.

Use it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    crossOrigin: true,
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

You can read more here: http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the responses.  Very helpful.  I decided to go with a proxy approach for which I found a simple solution here: http://www.paulund.co.uk/make-cross-domain-ajax-calls-with-jquery-and-php

For cut and paste simplicity I've added my code here.

I created a file called **crossdomain.html**.  Included jquery library. Created the following Javascript function:

```
function requestDataByProxy()
    {
        var url = "http://UrlYouWantToAcccess.html";
        var data = "url=" + url + "&parameters=1&para=2";    

        $.ajax({
            url: "our_domain_url.php",
            data: data,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                console.log('Success ' + data);
                $('#jsonData').html(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                console.log('Error ' + jqXHR);
            }
        });
    }
```

I also added a simple button and pre tag in HTML to load results:

```
<button onclick="requestDataByProxy()">Request Data By Proxy</button>

<h3>Requsted Data</h3>
<pre id="jsonData"></pre>
```

And then, the PHP file **our_domain_url.php** which uses cURL (make sure you have this enabled!)

```
<?php

//set POST variables
$url = $_POST['url'];
unset($_POST['url']);

$fields_string = "";
//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) { 
    $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
}
$fields_string = rtrim($fields_string,'&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($_POST));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

To me, this was a fairly straight-forward solution.

Hope this helps someone else!

Rob